# excel:find total_log of the max date for each group

Tags: excel

I hava a sheet1 like and it will update eveyday:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| company |   date   | total_log |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| A       | 20180910 |     32987 |
| A       | 20180902 |       426 |
| A       | 20180905 |     42135 |
| B       | 20180906 |     64743 |
| B       | 20180910 |    235647 |
| B       | 20180902 |      2346 |
| C       | 20180804 |     67536 |
| C       | 20180910 |     34536 |
| C       | 20180510 |    235356 |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

how to udate date and total_log column on sheet2 based on sheet1 with the max date for each company automaticly by Excel

```
+---------+------+-----------+
| company | date | total_log |
+---------+------+-----------+
| A       |      |           |
| B       |      |           |
| C       |      |           |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Formule For Sheet2 B2

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF($A1="company",1,MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11)), 2, 1,1, "Sheet1")&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11), 2, 1, 1)))
```

Formule For Sheet2 B3

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IF($A1="company",1,MATCH($A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11)), 3, 1,1, "Sheet1")&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11), 3, 1, 1)))
```